# selected rows of gridview not changing, instead all rows are changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a gridview that includes checkboxes and textboxes. What I want is when the particular row's checkbox is checked, the row's textbox will turn into dropdown.
I have used [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) feature to show dropdown and hide textbox.

This is the checkbox of gridview:

```
     <ItemTemplate>      <div style="text-align: center;">
           <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_id2" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Id") %>' />

                    <asp:CheckBox ID="NewCheckBoxImage" CssClass="NewCheckBoxImage()"  onClick="NewCheckBoxImage();" runat="server" /></div>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

And this is the code of javascript:

```
   function NewCheckBoxImage() {

        var flag = false;

        $('.gridAssigned input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {


            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                flag = true;
            }
        });
        if (flag) {

            $('.NewBtnAssign').show();
            $('.TextBoxCompany').hide();
            $('.TextBoxBrand').hide();
            $('.DDCompany').show();
            $('.DDBrand').show();

        }
        else {
            $('.NewBtnAssign').hide();
            $('.TextBoxCompany').show();
            $('.TextBoxBrand').show();
            $('.DDCompany').hide();
            $('.DDBrand').hide();
        }
    }
```

TextBoxCompany, TextBoxBrand are the textboxes and DDCompany, DDBrand are the dropdowns. When any checkbox is selected, then All the Textboxes get's hidden and all dropdowns shows up. I want the row(s) who's checkbox is selected, only those row's dropdown's appear.

Comment: You are selecting the elements by Class i.e. `.NewBtnAssign` this will find **every** element with that class and show it. Change your selectors to be something more specific.

Comment: OT: A side question: Why do post an asp.net tag instead of the renderend HTML output? I just want to understand why users posts also server side code, if there is a problem on clientside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting your elements by Class, this will return more than just the element for the current row. Try the below function :

```
   function NewCheckBoxImage() {
        $('.gridAssigned input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
            //Find the current row
            var row = $(this).parent().parent();

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                //Checkbox is Checked

                $(row).find('.NewBtnAssign').show();
                $(row).find('.TextBoxCompany').hide();
                $(row).find('.TextBoxBrand').hide();
                $(row).find('.DDCompany').show();
                $(row).find('.DDBrand').show();
            } else {
                $(row).find('.NewBtnAssign').hide();
                $(row).find('.TextBoxCompany').show();
                $(row).find('.TextBoxBrand').show();
                $(row).find('.DDCompany').hide();
                $(row).find('.DDBrand').hide();
            }
        });
    }
```

What this does is on every click of a checkbox it will itterate over the list of items and check if it is checked. If the item is checked it will then get the current HTML row using `$(this).parent().parent();` and then it will use the row to find the elements you need that exist within that row and show/hide them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

can you give this a try and let me know? I am not sure if it will work, but might

```
function NewCheckBoxImage() {

$('.gridAssigned input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        tr.find('.NewBtnAssign').show();
        tr.find('.TextBoxCompany').hide();
        tr.find('.TextBoxBrand').hide();
        tr.find('.DDCompany').show();
        tr.find('.DDBrand').show();
    }
    else {
        tr.find('.NewBtnAssign').hide();
        tr.find('.TextBoxCompany').show();
        tr.find('.TextBoxBrand').show();
        tr.find('.DDCompany').hide();
        tr.find('.DDBrand').hide();
    }
    });

}
```

Comment: @user2829939 i might have made some typo, basically its the same as the one you accepted. the only difference is `$(this).parent().parent();` and `$(this).closest('tr');`. I would recommend using `closest()` because the first method will not work if your checkbox inside another tag like `<span></span>`. read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)